# Expanding DOM lists to extract additional content with Python, Selenium, Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract content from [a page](https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.5.2) that is requires a list node to be selected. I have retrieve the page html using python and Selenium. Passing the page source to BS4 I can parse out the content that I am looking for using

```
   open_li = soup.select('div#tree ul.jstree-container-ul li')
```

Each list item returned has an

```
      aria-expanded = "false"  and class="jstree-node jstree-closed"
```

Looking at inspect element the content is called when these variables are set to

```
   aria-expanded = "true"  and class="jstree-node jstree-open"
```

I have tried using .click method on the content

```
  driver.find_element_by_id('tree').click()
```

But that only changes other content on the page. I think the list nodes themselves have to be expanded when making the request.

Does someone know how to change  aria-expand elements on a page before returning the content ?

Thanks

Comment: is  it possible to share the url ?

Comment: https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.5.2

Comment: I was able to get an output by clicking on it. "Project module (browse only dependencies of this module)" is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` package to get all information as a json. 
Here example how you can get all information the [page](https://app.updateimpact.com/api/singleArtifact?artifactId=commons-lang3&groupId=org.apache.commons&version=3.7):

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://app.updateimpact.com/api/singleArtifact?artifactId=commons-lang3&groupId=org.apache.commons&version=3.7"

    req_params = requests.get(url).json()
    response = requests.get(
        'https://app.updateimpact.com/api/builds/%s/%s' % (req_params["userIdStr"], req_params["buildId"]))
    print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for not getting the output

a) You are clicking on the wrong element

b) You are not waiting for the element to be loaded before clicking on it

c) You are not waiting for the content to be loaded after clicking on the element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
url="https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7"
driver.get(url)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7:jar_anchor"]/span')))
element.click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="tree-detail"]/div[2]/span[1]')))
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="detail_div"]').text)
```

Output

```
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7:jar (back)
Project module (browse only dependencies of this module)
Group id org.apache.commons
Artifact id commons-lang3
Version 3.7
Type jar
This dependency isn't a dependency of any other dependencies.
```

Comment: Thanks Bitto , although this doesn't quite hit what I was looking for as it does not expand the list.